# How to scroll Edit Text boxes upper side automatically in the layout in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 8 Edit Text Boxes and two buttons. For This i am uploading snap shoot of my application
[image]

Each of Edit Text Boxes i set KEYBOARD_12KEY for input type.
if i click on any Edit box then it appears as [image]

but if i click on edit box corresponding to G then it appears as [image]

the upper edit boxes scroll upper side but Edit Box corresponding to G covered by the buttons..but i want that if i click then whole edit boxes scroll upper side, no one edit box left down side the buttons. like :- [image]

can any one tell me how can i do this.

this is my xml file in the RelativeLayout -

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="A"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="B"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText02"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="C"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText03"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="D"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText04"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="E"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText05"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="true">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="F"/>

            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText06"></EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="G"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/EditText07"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="200dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="H"/>
            <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/EditText08"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/btnsLL" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="50dip" android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_below="@+id/configParamsLL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnResetCfg" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="2dip" android:layout_marginRight="50dip" android:text="Reset" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnSaveCfg" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="2dip" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" android:text="Save"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest so set the layout with the Buttons to

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and told the layout with the boxex to be locatet

```
android:layout_above="@id/ButtonsLayout"
```

but pay attentien the layout with the Buttons have to be declared ABOVE the Layout with the Textboxes.

Now the Buttons always will appear beneth the Edittext and the layout with the Edittext Controls (ScrollView) will have the focus on the selected editbox

edit:

As I said, the TableLayout with the buttons have to be over the Scrollview, but with alignParentBottom (without LayoutBelow) and the Scrollview must have a LayoutAbove tag:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/btnsLL" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="50dip" android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnResetCfg" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="2dip" 
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip" 
            android:text="Reset"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/BtnSaveCfg" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="2dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" 
            android:text="Save">
       </Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnsLL">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip" 
            android:minWidth="100dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:text="A"/>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="40dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText01">
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="B"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="C"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="D"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText04"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="E"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText05"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="true">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="F"/>

        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText06"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="G"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EditText07"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
         <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
             android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip" android:minWidth="200dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:text="H"/>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dip" android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/EditText08"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your menifest and check...

```
<activity android:name=".activity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```